# Какой вариант верен? (2)

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология, управление

В тесте было два варианта:

*удивлен результатом, уверенность в победе.*

Надо было найти вариант, в котором нарушена морфологическая норма.
На мой взгляд, оба варианта верны.

Comment: Нет. Задание стоит особняком

Comment: Было еще одно такое: две пары носков, килограмм яблок, несколько судоводителей

Comment: Морфология — это вообще о форме слова. То есть таких слов не должно быть в словарях.

Comment: В похожем тесте "пара носок". https://uchi.ru/otvety/questions/ukazhite-primer-s-oshibkoy-v-obrazovanii-formi-slova-1-kilogramm-yablok-2-opitnie-doktora

Comment: @oleedd вряд ли дело в "паре" и "двух парах". На "Грамоте" сказано, что "две пары носков" тоже верно.

Comment: Вопрос № 302478  
Добрый день. Как правильно написать: "Две пары носков" или "Две пары носок"

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Верно: две пары носков.

Comment: Имел в виду, что, может, они перепутали и там должно быть "носок" (ответ).

Comment: Два варианта чего? Это же совсем разные словосочетания.

Comment: @oleedd не слов, а форм слов. Вы смешали морфологические нормы с нормами словообразования.

Comment: @shampar Как я понимаю, это тест, в котором есть два варианта ответа. Нужно выбрать один (правильный либо неправильный).

Comment: @Ajgy Нет, слов. В словарях слова, а не формы слов. Морфология — раздел грамматики, изучающий морфемный состав языка, типы морфем, их взаимодействие. Словообразование с морфемами тоже связано: с помощью каких морфем образуется слово. Так что рассматривал бы не только форму, а и само слово. А ваше деление мне не нравится. [В задачи морфологии входит, таким образом, определение слова как особого языкового объекта и описание его внутренней **структуры**.](https://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/gumanitarnye_nauki/lingvistika/MORFOLOGIYA.html) Имел в виду структуру слов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заглянем в словарь [управления:](https://rus-upravlenie-dict.slovaronline.com/2365-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

удивлён — **чем**. *Удивлен его странным поведением*. Ср. *удивляться **чему***;

уверенность — **в чём** (не во что). *Уверенность в победе правого дела. Уверенность в своих силах. И он настойчиво, с непоколебимой **уверенностью в правде** своих пророчеств... говорил ей сказки о будущем* (Горький).

Рассмотрим примеры:

*Тут от Алекса потребовались некоторые актерские навыки, чтобы направить в кулак внутреннюю энергию, нанести удар и сделать вид, будто он сильно **удивлен результатом*** (А. Кош. Принцип Равновесия);
*Не спорил, потому что согласен был с планом Скобелева, зная не только обстановку, но и натуру самого командира отряда, его граничащую с безрассудством отвагу и несокрушимую **уверенность в победе*** (Б. Васильев. Были и небыли).

И вправду — оба варианта верны.

Comment: А что насчет подвопроса?

Comment: Э-э... Простите, что Вы имеете в виду, какой вопрос?

Comment: @МиМопи Разобралась, поняла, о чем Вы спрашиваете. Отвечаю дополнительно.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнительный ответ**

*Было еще одно такое: две пары носков, килограмм яблок, несколько судоводителей.*

Все три словосочетания верны, везде — Р. п., мн. ч. (носков, яблок, судоводителей).

[Пара](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0) (БТС) — **1.** Два однородных или одинаковых предмета, употребляемые вместе и составляющие одно целое. *Пара чулок. Две пары ботинок.*

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*Надевает на себя теплые рейтузы, штаны, **две пары носков**, два свитера, подпоясывается шерстяным платком и открывает настежь окна* (Маша Трауб. Замочная скважина);
*С ним вместе мы покупали ботинки желтые, узкие, щетку, **две пары носков** и часы* (К. И. Чуковский. Дневник);
*Так, вроде ничего не забыл. Две пары трусов и **две ― носков*** (Сергей Дигол. Не забудьте выключить).

Сочетание *две пары носок* в Нацкорпусе отсутствует.

Comment: @МиМопи  Благодарю за принятие ответа. Но — странное дело! — почему Вы не считаете нужным отмечать ответы как полезные? Ведь это работа, требующая и временных, и мозговых затрат. Прям обидно-таки.